# 'Document' object is not subscriptable Django

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error while uploading the excel file and saving that file.

My model.py file

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
```

In view i am saving that file to specific location
views.py file is

```
def excel(request):
    print "you in main"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "you in post"
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, newdoc)
            print path
            print "you in"
            newdoc.save()

            wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
            sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
            c = 1
            while c < len(sh.col(0)):
                first = sh.col_values(0)[c]
                second = sh.col_values(1)[c]
                c=c+1
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('upload.views.excel'))
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm() # A empty, unbound form
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('property/list.html',{'documents': documents, 'form': form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My html file is

```
<!-- List of uploaded documents -->
        {% if documents %}
            <ul>
            {% for document in documents %}
                <li><a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}">{{ document.docfile.name }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            <p>No documents.</p>
        {% endif %}

        <!-- Upload form. Note enctype attribute! -->
        <form action="/property/excel/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
            <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>
            <p>
                {{ form.docfile.errors }}
                {{ form.docfile }}
            </p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
        </form>
```

Error i am getting is

```
TypeError at /property/excel/
'Document' object is not subscriptable
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/property/excel/
Django Version: 1.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'Document' object is not subscriptable
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py in splitdrive, line 125
```

Please help me out to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

your problem is here:

```
path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, newdoc)
```

^ `newdoc` is a model instance and you don't want the model itself to be a part of your path - you want the uploaded file path there, thus:

```
path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, newdoc.docfile)
```

Comment: Hay i am getting error "'FieldFile' object has no attribute 'filename'"

Comment: so just `newdoc.docfile` then (or print the content `docfile` if there's some suitable property (`print dir(newdoc.docfile)`)